# Using SmbFile w/ groovy XmlSluper().parse() - Java

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I'm using the SmbFile method to read in an xml file from a network share. I then need to parse the file using the XmlSlurper().parse() method.

Normally I would do this using a File() method, but not sure how to do it using the SmbFile() network method. Is there a way to parse the network shared file using the method below, but w/ the SmbFile(). Maybe I would have to read in the file first then parse the string, not sure. Can someone quickly let me know?

```
File file = new File("C:/test.xml");
Object xmlIPSlup = new XmlSlurper().parse(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [this](http://www.jcifs.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html) is the `SmbFile` you're talking about you can always use [`getInputStream()`](http://www.jcifs.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html#getInputStream()) method but first you need to `connect` since `SmbFile` extends `URLConnection` - not a regular `File`.

`XmlSlurper` in turn has appropriate [method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#parse-java.io.InputStream-) for parsing `InputStream`.